# How can I move the whole leg in Pose Mode?

Tags: rigging, bones, makehuman

I'm here:

[image]

I would like to move the whole leg. My version in 2.74. I follow a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPYbdnPwHuQ.

It's a v2.71 and it's different version than mine. I tried to do it with different options:

[image]

Blend File:

[image]

Comment: your setup is not identical to the one in the video, so it is better to share the blend, eg:  http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @m.ardito I've attached the blend file. thanks